# docker entrypoint using dos2unix

Tags: docker, dockerfile

- When I run *docker-compose up -d --build*
- The dockerfile does not trigger the CMD bash /webapp/runscript.sh
- Said differently...I don't see the redis-server or celery application running when I exec into the container
- If I manually run "bash /webapp/runscrip.sh"; the processes end up running
- I originally tried *Entrypoint ['bash', '/webapp/runscript.sh']* as well
  with no luck. Not sure what I am missing

tail-end of dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir -p /logs

COPY runscript.sh /webapp/runscript.sh
RUN chmod -R u+x /webapp/runscript.sh
RUN dos2unix /webapp/runscript.sh
CMD bash /webapp/runscript.sh

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

runscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup redis-server > /logs/redis.out &
nohup celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info > /logs/celery_worker.out &
nohup celery flower -A app.celery > /logs/celery_flower.out &
```

Comment: Generally you'd do those sorts of installation steps via RUN commands in your Dockerfile, so it happens once no matter how many times you run the image.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, and edited the question.  I am still facing similar issue on the running of the script. Is there anyway to troubleshoot the logs while a container is being started...and the script being run

Comment: In this iteration of the question, your first `CMD` is ignored in favor of the second; the `runscript.sh` you show can't be the main process in a container because nothing is the foreground process that keeps the container alive.  I'd suggest running these three tasks as foreground tasks in three separate containers.

Comment: In this particular case, I am actually trying to run redis and celery on a single Ubuntu instance, as apposed to separating out into multipe containers. I've removed the second CMD  'tail -f /dev/null" and added a "sleep 30" to the end of the runscript.sh. It still doesn't start the redis-sever or celery workers as expected. To note after the 30 seconds the container is still active as there is a flask app running on it to keep active

Comment: what is `CMD tail -f /dev/null` for? Did you try to remove it and use `ENTRYPOINT /webapp/runscript.sh` instead of CMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMD` step in a Dockerfile sets meta data on the image telling docker the default command to run when running the container. You can only have a single value for `CMD` so setting it a second time overwrites any previous settings.

Containers can only have a single process to start, and that process is run as pid 1 inside the container. Once that process exits, the entire container is stopped, including any background processes run.

Therefore, you need to set the `CMD` to whatever command or script you want to run, and that command needs to remain running for the duration of your container's lifetime. That could be as easy as running `tail -f /dev/null` as the last line of your script. However the recommended practice is to run your app in the foreground rather than background daemons that may crash unnoticed. I'd you really need multiple daemons inside a container, there's tools like supervisord. But in most cases, you are better off running multiple containers, one per service, and communicate between those services over a shared docker network. `docker-compose` is very useful to setup this network and deploy your containers with the appropriate configurations.

Comment: My reasoning for creating a single Ubuntu 16.04 image with redis-server and celery workers running was because I have a EC2 instance that I want to deploy my code on. I'm current developing on a windows machine and trying to mimic a Linux environment where I will deploy the code against with no environment issues. So I guess, it's ill-advised to do what I'm doing? How do I keep costs down if I would need to spin up the same containers on AWS if I split up each the processes? I'd appreciated any helpful insight or links, new to dockerizing. I'll try looking into supervisord in the meantime

Comment: @Karun you can run multiple containers on the same EC2 host. That's part of the selling point, application isolation rather than OS isolation. By using separate containers and images, you only need to update specific pieces rather than everything every time, and you can take advantage of pre built and maintained images.